# Database queries with SELECT xxx FROM database WHERE Relay = "value from a string"

Tags: python, sqlite, select

I'm wondering about if it's possible to get data from a database with this query: `SELECT Name FROM fraleon WHERE Relay = "value from a string"`?
When I try to put in a string in the query it comes with a message that the column doesn't exists.

I have just started with programming, so hope my question isn't to stupid ;-) I'm trying to make an app where i have a QtableWidget and a QScrollbar where the value from the scrollbar (1 - 100) is used to change to the next relay.

```
con = sqlite3.connect("C:\Leonclient\LocalDB\LeonDBlite.db")cur = con.cursor()
value = 5
       
for row in cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM fraleon where Relay = value'):
    print(row)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10292/3072186007.py", line 1, in <module>
    for row in cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM fraleon where Relay = (Value)'):

OperationalError: no such column: Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to concatenate the query string with variable value otherwise it will be considered literally 'value'

```
for row in cur.execute('SELECT Name FROM fraleon where Relay = ' + str(value)):
```

Comment: Thanks :) That solved my problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write the query -
`SELECT Name FROM fraleon WHERE Relay like  '%somevalue%'`

That way you will specify a sub-string of the Relay's column values

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I see that I should have asked differently because it partly solved my problem with doing it like Jayvee suggested me to do. It was the solution on my problem with putting in at string in the query, but not the hole problem :)